# Adding "terms" on the fly and/or mutiple term referance submission with "unlimted values"

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have an issue which I’m hoping you guys can point me in the direction.  I’m currently building a music press/media site in which I want to use “terms” for things like the artists, venues etc.  Eventually writers will be able to submit their work via the normal add content route and all the various terms will be created when there filling out the submission form.  At the moment I’m using a “Term Reference” field with the “Autocomplete term widget (tagging)” widget to add in the main artist.  I have a separate field for the support artists  with the Number of Values option set to “unlimited” however I don’t get an option to add another support artist in (like you would if the fields reference was set to text).

So I’m looking for a way to get an option within the node submission form to keep on adding support artists as term references  and/or a method of adding term references on the fly so they can be selected via a drop down list whilst the submission form is being filled out (i..e not the term references are add and in place before the form is saved.
Any help on this would be mostly appreciated as this has had me stuck for a while now.

Thanks.

Comment: Hello Dangerous Dave, welcome to DA! Since we're trying to create as generic and canonical resources as we can on this site, may I please ask you to re-phrase the question so it's less specific to _your particular_ use case. The widget behaviour you want to have is after all applicable to a wider audience.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you try the [Hierarchical Select](http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) module if you want to have a drop down select as well as have the ability to add new terms on the fly. You select this option when setting up the Hierarchical Select for the term reference field. It will add 'Add new term' to the select list.

Comment: I shall give this a go and report back.  Thank you very much! :)

Comment: After playing with the Hierarchical Select module I can confirm that this looks like its going to be perfect for the job, thanks again!